# How to make mouse change position on mouse click?

Tags: actionscript-3

So, I'm trying to make a gun aim at the crosshair, so it follows the mouse all the time. I want it to go up on recoil, so the mouse crosshair goes up and the gun follows up.

I tried something like mouseY - 10; but with no luck, it didn't do anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot set the position of the mouse.

Instead, set the Position of the cross hair.

Comment: I put "crosshair.x = mouseX; crosshair.y = mouseY;" at the enterframe. I put "crosshair.y -= 10;" at the mouseclick event. It seems like it can't move if it's attached to the mouse, if I dettach it, it moves fine. Is there any othere way to put the crosshair at the mouse and make it change position at the same time?

Comment: It should not come as a surprise that if you set the position to be the same as the mouse 30 times per second (or whatever your framerate is), any single position change will not last very long. Instead of setting the position equal to the mouse in the ENTER_FRAME event, make it move towards the mouse. crosshair.x += (mouseX - crosshair.x)/5; Experiment with other values than 5 to find a desired behaviour.

Comment: Alright, thanks but now when I set it so the gun follows the crosshair instead of the mouse. I used "var dx = mouseX - x;" and changed to "var dx = crosshair.x - x;" but now nothing happens. This is in the gun class enterframe to rotate the gun.

Comment: Oh, sorry I forgot to parent it. Thanks for your answer!